# Open Visual Studio Code's terminal in a root of current project, is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) has this feature, when I open terminal it's already at the root of current project. Unlike it, [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) opens terminal in a home folder, can this behavior be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was frustrating for me as well, to go to my project's root folder via the integrated terminal in `VScode`. However, I installed this plugin and it worked for me:

[VSCode Terminal Here Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here)

I'm not sure whether they have this feature in-built now.

This is [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15531) to the discussion how I got to know about the plugin.

Hope it works for you as well :)

PS - If you don't like to use a plugin, you can check this option in user-settings

`"terminal.integrated.cwd": ""`

I have never tried it, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

My absolute fav @code shortcut is `⌘ + Shift + C` : Opens terminal in the current project directory.

https://twitter.com/burkeholland/status/908754875995082752

Comment: Great shortcut. To add to this you can choose which default terminal gets open using a json setting for example I wanted to open Powershell Core on Windows `"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\6\\pwsh.exe"`

Answer (score -2):

Just open a new terminal tab in VSCode and it will be located in the current project directory

Comment: This did not work for me.